# How do I apply a customized MUI component which pulls from an external theme js file to a third js file's JSX?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

So I have three separate js files I am working on. Those are 'theme.js', 'MyCustomButton.js', and 'CrashCourse1.js'.

theme.js code:

```js
import { createTheme, colors } from '@mui/material';

const theme = createTheme({
  palette: {
    primary: {
      main: colors.green[700],
      light: colors.green[200],
      dark: colors.green['A700'],
    },
    secondary: {
      main: colors.blue[600],
      light: colors.blue[300],
      dark: colors.blue[900],
    },
    text: {
      primary: colors.grey[700],
      secondary: colors.grey[700],
    },
    myCustomColor: {
      main: colors.red[400],
      superDark: colors.red[800],
      superLight: colors.red[100],
    },
  },

  typography: {
    myVariant: {
      fontSize: '1rem',
      color: colors.orange[500],
    },
  },
  myCustomButton: {
    myVariant: {
      variant: 'contained'
    }
  }
});

export default theme;
```

---

*MyCustomButton.js*

```js
import { styled } from "@mui/material";
import { Button } from '@mui/material';
//import theme from './theme'; //Do I need this?

export const CustomButton = styled(Button)(({ theme }) => ({
  // color: , //How would I write this to use primary.main for example?
  // variant: 'contained' //How would I write this

}));
```

---

CrashCourse1.js code:

```js
import { Fragment } from 'react';
import { Typography } from '@mui/material';

import CustomButton from '../styles/MyCustomButton';

const MuiCrashCourse1 = () => {

  return (
    <Fragment>
      <Typography variant="myVariant">This is my app</Typography>
      <Typography sx={{ color: 'myCustomColor.superLight' }}>Hit the like button!</Typography>
      <CustomButton>Hello from MUI V5</CustomButton>
    </Fragment>
  )
}

export default MuiCrashCourse1;
```

How do I get this to work where I can separate the theme that is applied in the first file to the second file which is the custom styled mui component and then successfully import that to the CrashCourse1.js file in order to see those styles applied to my CustomButton component?

Comment: And I'd like to see those styles applied to '<CustomButton>Hello from MUI V5</CustomButton>' without having to put in "variant='contained'" in the component within the CrashCourse1.js file

Comment: primary.main should be `theme.palette.primary.main` using the theme provided via `styled`. To override the default variant you should look at [default props](https://mui.com/material-ui/customization/theme-components/#default-props). For the theme to work at all you need to use a `ThemeProvider` and give it your created theme.